# Regex for email validation not working in Spring DOJO

Tags: javascript, regex, spring, dojo

I want to validate an email address using Spring Decoration of DOJO framework. but the regex which used to work in normal validation is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                        elementId: "emailAddress",
                        widgetType: "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
widgetAttrs: 
    {                             
    regExp : "/^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,4}$/",
    required:"true",                         
    invalidMessage:"<span class='graytext'>Invalid format for email Address.<br> </span>",
    trim:"true"
                        }
                        }));
```

Why is my regExp is not working here in the Spring decoration of DOJO?

Comment: With which email addresses are you testing it? That regex will fail on some valid ones.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8829363/1587329 for a stackoverflow-approved email regex ;-): spoiler: <code>^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$<code> (had a backtick, so formatting cannot be done via backtick)

Comment: I'm trying to test a simple mail id: amit.kamath@gmail.com

Comment: The  regExp : "^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w\\-\\'])*[\\w]*[@]([A-Za-z0-9]{1}[\\.\\w_-]*)[.][A-Za-z]{2,10}",  works well. But I dont want to keep a highly restrictive validation. I want to use the other regex.

Comment: That regex won't match ant new top level domains like .travel - consider scrapping it altogether

Comment: If anyone wonders later about backticks inside backticks, you can [use multiple backticks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362): ``^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0‌​-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$``

Answer (score 2):

All you need to make this regex work is remove the regex delimiters (leading and trailing `/`) since the [DOJO regexp](https://github.com/nraychaudhuri/spring-akka-sample/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/javascript/dojo/regexp.js) already escapes the special regex characters:

```
regExp : "^[\w.=-]+@[\w.-]+\.\w{2,4}$"
```

Also, inside a character class, you do not have to escape the `.` and you do not have to enclose single `\w` into a character class.

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Please remember that this does not work with the new TLDs. If you have a website with `.travel`, `.ninja`, ... then this regular expression will not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding double backslashes: `"/^[\\w\\.=-]+@[\\w\\.-]+\.[\\w]{2,4}$/"`